# Getting an error with Twitter Package in Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, python-twitter

I have installed Python 2.7 and trying to use Twitter package. I have installed the 3 pre-requisite packages successfully... But somehow getting this error:

```
>>> import twitter
>>> api = twitter.Api()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in <module>
    api = twitter.Api()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Api'
```

The I tried this version but got the same error:

```
>>> api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
                  consumer_secret='consumer_secret',
                  access_token_key='access_token',
                  access_token_secret='access_token_secret')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in <module>
    api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Api'
```

I have installed 3 packages for twitter namely:
python-twitter-0.8.5, python-twitter-1.0, twitter-1.10.0

and the output of the command is as below:

```
>>> twitter.__file__
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\twitter-1.10.0-py2.7.egg\\twitter\\__init__.pyc'
```

Should I be uninstalling something? I have renamed twitter.py files in python-twitter-0.8.5 and python-twitter-1.0 but still getting the error...

Comment: What does `twitter.__file__` tell you you imported? You probably have another file called `twitter.py` in your current working directory. Rename that, it is masking the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed a *different* Twitter API module; you installed [`twitter` 1.10.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter), not [`python-twitter`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-twitter). The APIs between the two projects differ significantly:

```
import twitter

t = twitter.Twitter(
        auth=twitter.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET,
                   CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
       )
```

You may want to uninstall `twitter` and install `python-twitter` instead.

However, if all you need is a good Twitter API package for Python, take a look at the [list that Twitter maintains](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries). [Tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy) and a *different* [`python-twitter` package](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) are under active maintenance.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue with Python-twitter that I see is that there are 2 such packages...  python-twitter-0.8.5 & python-twitter-1.0 and moreover both of them supports Python 2.4 and not Python 2.7. So until I had installed twitter1.10 package, it was complaining that Python 2.4 does not exist...

Comment: @user2607677: updated with better alternatives. There are some conflicting packages around.